# Why do I get worse result after normalizing my input data of LSTM?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, normalization, lstm

The first pic shows my data before normalization:

[image]

And the second pic show my data after normalization using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` :

[image]

I get better result with the natural data. How is it possible? Is that mean I shouldn't normalize my data to feed the LSTM network?